# Vagrant box broken after sleep/shutdown

Tags: vagrant

This has happened several times now, the scenario is as follows: I create/provision a vagrant box with puppet. I work on it for some time, a couple of days, sometimes a week. At the end of my day I either close the lid on my MacBook (putting it to sleep), or I shut it down. At a certain point, `vagrant up` gives an error:

```
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant
```

Provisioning, reloading, halt/up all don't work at this point. I have to destroy and build the box again, which costs some time and becomes very annoying.

I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vagrant-up/aSZkYyoC8sY/dWF1JoP65pcJ) which describes this problem, and states a ntp service should fix it. So I've added that to my puppet config, but the problem still occurs.

I also found a similar [issue on Github](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/672), which is fixed, but I'm running a different OS than described there, so it's not the same issue. I did post my problem there, without response so far.

The debug log is saved as a gist: https://gist.github.com/pkruithof/5116426

Does anyone know what this problem might be, and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**
I think this is fixed somewhere along the road in Vagrant, because I haven't had this issue in about 6 months now. Therefore I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Add the following lines:

> [keyfile]
>
> unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0

Do vargrant reload

Comment: I'm very interested in this solution, but my Laravel Homestead (Vagrant) box doesn't even have a `/etc/NetworkManager/` directory yet, so I'm confused about this. Can you please explain what this file is supposed to do (and why I have never needed this file before) and what these lines do? Thanks!